# Determine number of contacts with Google People API

Tags: google-people-api

I am using the Google People API to fetch a user's connections, and since the results do not include email addresses, phone numbers, etc. after I call people.connections.list and retrieve a total of 50 results I am then polling people:batchGet to fetch data for the users (which only accepts up to 50 users at a time). This works fine, and after looping over the results a few times I can import all of the contacts. Great!

But because of this setup and the need to loop (some users have thousands of connections after all) I am using a process that (basically) redirects over and over until we're done. This is also working fine, but I'd love to show a progress bar on the redirect screens, and in order to do this I'd need to know the total number of connections the user has. I can't seem to find any way to determine the number of total results that people.connections.list could return (provided no filters or sync tokens are passed in). Does anyone know a way I can determine how many connections total that we need to loop over with people.connections.list?

Comment: Do you also get "Other contacts" from the contacts list?

Comment: No, I'm only fetching the primary contacts.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? This works for me in Java.

```
// Get the user's connections
ListConnectionsResponse r = peopleService.people().connections()
        .list("people/me")
        .setPageSize(500)
        // specify fields to be returned
        .setRequestMaskIncludeField("person.names,person.emailAddresses")
        .execute();

List<Person> connections = r.getConnections();
System.out.println(connections.size());
```

You could also add what fields to be included if you use something like this URL:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=500&requestMask.includeField=person.names%2Cperson.emailAddresses&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I am using PHP. Your pseudo-code would get the size of the connection list I assume, but what I am after is the total number of connections had there been no limit specified. e.g. let's say the user has 4500 contacts and I fetch 50 of them - I have fetched approximately 1% of the contacts. Then I fetch 50 more I'm up to 2%, and so on. What I'm looking for is a way to determine that value of 4500 from the API, which I can't seem to find.

Answer (score -2):

There is a recently added [totalItems](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#response-body) field on the list response which should return the total number of people in the list.

However, the better fix is that you should request email addresses, phone numbers, etc. in the [request mask](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#query-parameters) for the list call

Comment: `totalItems` is the right way to get count (and hence implement progress bar). `RequestMask` won't help you with progress bar but will help limit the number of fields in the returned response objects. By the way, why is this answer downvoted? The only edit required in answer is removal of "the better fix is that"